# Interpreting Output of Bayesian Regression Modeling in R

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, interpretation, brms

I'm trying to find out

1. if the metaphor and political affiliation influences the response category, and
2. if the vignette length influences the reported reliability

I used this code:

```
fit <- brm(
  formula = response_category ~ metaphor * affiliation + (1 | submission_id), 
  data = dat,
  family=cumulative("logit")
  )
fit2 <- brm(
  formula = as.numeric(reliability) ~ vignetteLength, 
  data = dat
)
```

However, I don't know how to interpret the output.

```
summary(fit)
 Family: cumulative 
  Links: mu = logit; disc = identity 
Formula: response_category ~ metaphor * affiliation + (1 | submission_id) 
   Data: dat (Number of observations: 60) 
  Draws: 4 chains, each with iter = 2000; warmup = 1000; thin = 1;
         total post-warmup draws = 4000

Group-Level Effects: 
~submission_id (Number of levels: 60) 
              Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sd(Intercept)    28.33     24.04     5.83    90.54 1.01      291      219

Population-Level Effects: 
                                      Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
Intercept[1]                              3.18      9.80   -12.19    28.45 1.01      492      270
Intercept[2]                             11.65     11.95    -1.93    46.75 1.01      374      276
Intercept[3]                             74.30     64.79    15.08   236.54 1.01      282      212
metaphorvirus                             0.91     15.05   -32.10    35.85 1.01      456      325
affiliationneither                       12.50     15.76   -10.81    53.13 1.00      524      493
affiliationrathernotsay                  43.12     67.97   -27.66   200.30 1.01      464      200
affiliationRepublican                    38.55     39.21     1.33   139.40 1.01      325      258
metaphorvirus:affiliationneither         -0.07     21.97   -47.55    45.75 1.01      502      496
metaphorvirus:affiliationrathernotsay    -4.33     67.57  -135.60   125.63 1.01      579      297
metaphorvirus:affiliationRepublican     -10.76     30.82   -88.63    47.65 1.00      568      492

Family Specific Parameters: 
     Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
disc     1.00      0.00     1.00     1.00   NA       NA       NA

Draws were sampled using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).
Warning message:
There were 13 divergent transitions after warmup. Increasing adapt_delta above 0.8 may help. See http://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#divergent-transitions-after-warmup 

summary(fit2)
 Family: gaussian 
  Links: mu = identity; sigma = identity 
Formula: as.numeric(reliability) ~ vignetteLength 
   Data: dat (Number of observations: 60) 
  Draws: 4 chains, each with iter = 2000; warmup = 1000; thin = 1;
         total post-warmup draws = 4000

Population-Level Effects: 
                            Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
Intercept                       4.90      0.33     4.25     5.54 1.00     3809     2919
vignetteLengthshortvignette     0.26      0.43    -0.58     1.11 1.00     3841     3191

Family Specific Parameters: 
      Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sigma     1.62      0.15     1.35     1.96 1.00     3799     2807

Draws were sampled using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).
```

I'm sorry if this is a very basic question. I am new to Statistics. I only know how to interpret R squared and t-values, etc. but it doesn't say anything of that in the output.

Comment: AS @BenBolker has said, it ismportant that you don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: @Miriam: Do you have any knowledge of Bayesian statistics?

Comment: If you don't mind some formulae and a bit of mathematics/statistics, then [this article](https://doi.org/10.1177/25152459188231) by the author of the brms package might be a good starting point on what the various terms in the model mean and what is going on in the background.

Comment: @Björn: Unfortunately, I can't open the link. It says: DOI not found. Could you send me the title and authors instead, please?

Comment: @Miriam Try #2: Bürkner P-C, Vuorre M. Ordinal Regression Models in Psychology: A Tutorial. Advances in Methods and Practices in Psychological Science. 2019;2(1):77-101. doi:10.1177/2515245918823199 It's also available via PsyArXiv: https://psyarxiv.com/x8swp/